# Rename column in existing table in sql server where column name is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, rename

I want to rename column in sql server because I forgot to give name to one column. I have also tried the query below but it is not working either:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.[]' , '[Frequency of compliance]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: how did you even create a column without name. It is a required field!

Comment: You're title says it's called `' '`, however, in your SQL you have `''`. I assume you therefore should be doing `TableName.[ ]`. How, or why, you achieved this is beyond me though. >_<

Comment: I imported excel file where in one column there is no heading/column name. After uploading file I found that column name is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQL Server Management Studio interactive interface, expand the DB and expand the tables and then right click on the table name to display the options, and then choose design

you can rename, change the type, add columns, including delete columns, and many others that you can do to design your table

After you finish designing, just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the change, this is really simple and easiest way to design your tables

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not possible in SQL server.

You should instead do this to find the actual column name:

```
select c.name from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on c.object_id=t.object_id and t.name='TableName'
```

This will give you the name of all the columns from table.
You should seek the right name and then rerun `sp_rename` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Empty columnnames are not allowed in sql server, but they can only consist of spaces.

To rename it you can add space(s) between `[]`.
Also you need to remove the square brackets from the new columnname, otherwise the columnname will be `[Frequency of compliance]` including the brackets.
But I would recommend to completely not use spaces inside columnnames.

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.[ ]' , 'Frequency of compliance', 'COLUMN'
```

Another possibility is to use the design-mode in SSMS.